# How to change multiple form elements via single select

Tags: html, forms, select, if-statement, onchange

I'm completely stumped at how I can change the opening  tag to have 'method=post' if the second select option is chosen. I am using an Onchange for the form action, but can't figure out how to change the post method too. 
My latest attempt is with an IF statement as shown in the below code, but again, only 1 option will work.

```
if(this.value){
    $content .='<form action="/gsresults">';
    }
else{
    $content .='<form action="/imagesearch?go" method="post">';
}
$content .='<input type="text" name="q"/>

 <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="partner-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx" />
        <input type="hidden" name="cof" value="FORID:11" />
        <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8" />


          <select onchange="this.form.action=this.value">
        <option value="/gsresults" selected="selected">Google</option>
        <option value="/imagesearch?go">Images</option>
    </select>

        <input type="submit" name="sa"/> 
</form>';
```

Thanks for any help/pointers.

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jQuery to listen for an event and edit the form's attributes:

```
$("select").change(function() {
  $("form").attr("method","post");
});
```

I'd suggest adding in an `id` on both your `<form>` and your `<select>` so your listeners don't get confused.

Comment: Thank you JLF, I am still not getting it to work but I appreciate your help. I am not to familiar with Jquery/JavaScript as I'm not a programmer but can hack a bit of PHP around my site to usually get things working, however not this time. Thank you anyway

Comment: OK - Update. I persevered! and cracked it. Thanks for putting me on the right track. Highly appreciated!


 <script type="text/javascript" src=\'//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js\'></script>
  <script>
   jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery("#site").on("change", function() {
    
 jQuery("#myForm").attr("method","post");
});
 
 </script>